# Open browser with URL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-yosemite

I've been using the following to launch the default browser in OS X:

```
system('open', url)
```

This has been working fine until upgrading to Yosemite.  Now, I frequently get this message when trying to open various URLS:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the URL http://blah.com
```

But sometimes that URL will work.  I can try it once, and it'll work, another it might not.  Very unpredictable.

I've tried all of these:

```
system("open #{url}")
`open #{url}`
Launchy.open(url, debug: true)

Launchy.open( "#{ url }" ) do |exception|
  puts "Attempted to open #{url} and failed because #{exception}"
end
```

But they all exhibit this same behavior.  There are several URLs being opened at once, like this:

```
urls.each do |url|
  system("open #{url}")
end
```

How can I consistently open a specific URL in my browser on OS X using ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are pushing the Browser with too many urls at the same time.

Using `sleep` seems to work fine.

```
15.times {|i| `open http://google.com?q=#{i}` }
# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the URL http://google.com?q=5.
# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the URL http://google.com?q=6.
# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the URL http://google.com?q=12.
# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -1712 for the URL http://google.com?q=14.
# => 15
15.times {|i| sleep(0.2); `open http://google.com?q=#{i}` }
# => 15
```